# Generating Certificates using Certbot (as a CronJob) within Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I've unsuccessfully been trying to create a simple "run" command using kubectl whereby the container is started and passed in the (partial) arguments to initially create my certificates (which I will initially do manually through PowerShell) and could do with some input from the community.

**My Environment**:

- (Local) Windows 10 with PowerShell
- (Remote) Azure Kubernetes Cluster

My efforts consist of two key commands, the first being the creation of the overrides (in JSON) for the container (primarily so I can mount the Azure File Shares where I want certificates to be stored):

```
$override= '{ "spec": { "template": { "spec": { "containers": [ { "name": "certbot", "image": "certbot/certbot", "stdin": true, "tty": true, "volumeMounts": [{ "name": "certdata", "mountPath": "/etc/letsencrypt" }] } ], "volumes": [{ "name": "certdata", "persistentVolumeClaim": { "claimName": "azure-fileshare" } }] } } } }' | ConvertTo-Json
```

The second is then the kubectl run command which would be used as the basis for the CronJob (creating the CronJob itself is my next task once I've gotten this working correctly):

```
kubectl run -i --rm --tty certbot --namespace=prod --overrides=$override --image=certbot/certbot -- certonly --manual
```

I've been trying a number of variations, and this approach seems the cleanest. However, I'm currently getting the following response from Kubernetes:

```
Error attaching, falling back to logs: unable to upgrade connection: container certbot not found in pod certbot-9df67bd65-w96rq_prod
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Certbot doesn't know how to automatically configure the web server on this system. However, it can still get a certificate for you. Please run "certbot certonly" to do so. You'll need to manually configure your web server to use the resulting certificate.
```

The latter part of the warning indicates that certbot is not receiving any of the arguments (in this case "certonly" and "--manual"), but I can't figure out quite where I'm going wrong. I feel like I've sanity checked the commands with both the Kubernetes & certbot docs and can't see any obvious issues.

Can anyone point out the gremlin here?

**Note**: I've successfully tested this approach using Docker locally, and am now trying to recreate this within Azure.

Comment: well, from what I can tell the container just exits. whats the output of `kubectl get po -n production`?

Comment: @4c74356b41 thanks for your response :) You're quite right, the container does just exit, as it doesn't detect any off the arguments required to initiate certbot into creating certificates manually (hence the last error message). 

I ran your command and it just shows the existing container I have running in production, but not the certbot container discussed above.

Comment: why do you think so? i'm pretty sure if you do `kubectl run -i --rm --tty certbot --namespace=prod --overrides=$override --image=certbot/certbot -- /bin/sh` it will work just fine

Comment: @4c74356b41 The entrypoint for the docker image being used is the certbot command. So when you start the container, it's expecting certbot arguments to be passed in. If the arguments are not passed in, then certbot just outputs the last line of the error message in my question ("Certbot doesn't know" etc.). I've tried your suggested command for running that image but the same output is observed. It's a frustrating one, but no doubt I've missed something here!

Comment: just create a certbot with overridden entrypoint. thats your problem, certbot cant be a tty, so you cant attach to it

Comment: @4c74356b41 Ouch! Of course, that would make sense. Testing locally, Docker didn't require me to override the run command as I could natively mount volumes using -v (rather than using the override to achieve it). Looks like I may need to create a bespoke / derived image to achieve what I need to do then!

Thank you soo much for your help :) If you want to copy your comment to an answer I will mark it as the accepted response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to create a image from image to do that, just create a pod like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: certbot
spec:
  containers:
  - name: certbot
    image: certbot/certbot
    command: ["/bin/sh"] << this overrides entrypoint
  restartPolicy: Never
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/

Comment: Thank you, you're a legend :) Really appreciate the help!